# continuous partial derivatives with constant over circles are not zero

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ with continuous partial derivatives
>   such that $f(C_i),$ for $i=1,2,3$ is constant over $C_i$ being a
>   circle of radius $1$ with centers at $(-1,0), (1,0), (0,\sqrt 3$).
>
> Then exists a point $p \in \bigcup_i C_i $ where $\nabla f = 0 $

I have no idea where to start, the only thing I noticed is that the circles touch in $3$ points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $f$ is constant on a circle $C$, it means that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the circle at every point of $C$. If $\nabla f$ is never $0$, it means that it is constantly directed outwards, or constantly inwards the circle.

Comment: But it can't be on the same circle $C$ that the $\nabla f$ points outwards somewhere and inwards somewhere else because of the continuity of the partial derivatives? (if it does change, then it's zero at the point where it changes?)

Comment: Think about it. You have 3 circles. On some of them the gradient points outwards, on some of them it points inwards. There is a contradiction somewhere.